# XML File output failure

Tags: xml, oracle, file, plsql

I am trying to output an xml file using the below code. Issue arises when there is large amount of data, it cannot output the file due to size of the variable. Your help will be highly appreciated here. NOTE: the select statement used outputs the xml format. Thank you.

Code:

```
DECLARE
    l_file    UTL_FILE.file_type;
    l_xmltype xmltype;

BEGIN
    SELECT XMLRoot(
            XMLElement("report", 
            XMLELEMENT ("rentity_id", '40'), 
            --.... more xml elements goes here.... 
            ),  VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8') 
    INTO l_xmltype

    FROM 
        Table1, Table2, Table3
    WHERE   
        --conditions go here... ; 

    l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen ('XMLDIR', 'XMLFile.XML', 'w');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(l_file , l_xmltype.getStringVal( ));
    UTL_FILE.fclose (l_file);
end;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit error msg: "Character string buffer too small"  *Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back *Action:   Get the result as a lob instead.

Comment: @Jey.S Change `l_xmltype xmltype;` to `l_xmltype clob;` and try once.

Comment: Hi @XING, already tried it, error: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 127, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CLOB got -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 222, column 38:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'L_XMLTYPE'

Comment: Remove `" encoding="UTF-8` and try again.

Comment: Hello @WernfriedDomscheit, same error persists as there are more characters '-' in the select part.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something along the lines of the below, not sure if of syntax can't test right now but should start you along the right path. Assuming that l_string is varchar2(1000) and l_pos is number.

```
l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen ('XMLDIR', 'XMLFile.XML', 'w');
l_string := null;
l_pos := 0;
while l_pos < l_xmltype.getStringVal( ).length() loop
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(l_file , substr(l_xmltype.getStringVal( ), l_pos + 1, l_pos + 1000);
  l_pos := l_pos + 1000;
end loop;
UTL_FILE.fclose (l_file);
```